# Naming C# classes from bad table columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have used Entity Framework and a SQL Server database until now. So I can represent my table name as a class name and property names as properties like following.

```
class Product{ 
      public string Id { get; set;} 
      public string Name { get; set;} 
}
```

The table and column names are the same with my class.

But now I will work a project that uses a Postgresql database. Table names and column names are like this.

- Tables `products`, `product_categories` (lowercase)
- Columns `product_id, product_name, category_id`, ....

So I do not want to use class names like this:

```
class products { 
      public string product_id { get; set; }
      public string product_name { get; set; }
      public string category_id { get; set; }
}
```

This  looks like an ugly naming conventions. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you talking about something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944974/t4-fieldname-in-camelcase-without-underscore

Comment: EF has the ability to use metadata to annotate field names, see (https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20First%20Annotations) and you can use a PostGreSql provider with EF (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/783552/Using-PostgreSQL-with-Entity-Framework-in-ASP-NET)

Answer (score 6):

Use table and column attributes. From [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx):

```
[Table("InternalBlogs")]
public class Blog
{   
    [Column("BlogDescription", TypeName="ntext")]
    public String Description {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a code-first approach? I am unclear if the OP has the option for this. Just asking I am curious. Tnx

Comment: Yes, I think it's code first. OP was unclear on which technique he was using. So if the OP or anyone else with a similar issue has this question and happens to be using code first, this should be useful. I'm assuming code first since he wrote out the class himself (unless that was just intended to be representative of what EF was doing with model or DB first)

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to map entities to your domain classes which you name using standard C# conventions.

So this table `product_id, product_name, categori_id, ..` you map to:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
}
```

Then you create a mapper helper that translates entity to the domain object:

```
public Product ProductMapper(EntityProduct entity)
{
    return new Product
    {
        Id = entity.product_id,
        Name = entity.product_name,
        Category = entity.category_id,
    }
}
```

I leave for you to decide whether a mapper should be a separate helper class, a static method on the `Product` class. Also, when saving the data you reverse the process, that is you map the domain object into an entity.